# Do I still need PhantomJS or prerender.io for crawlers

Tags: angularjs, akamai

I am revamping a project in which i am using `AngularJS in frontend`. But i was stuck in issue to serve pages to crawlers. On local we are not using `akamai`, but on staging and production we have implemented it (with old stack).

My question is when i replace my frontend from `PHP to AngularJS` do i need to implement that `prerender.io` or other tools like same to provide my page to crawlers. As `akamai` store pages in plan html, so will `akamai` is capable of same or do i need to implement that `prerender.io` or is there some other plugin in `akamai` which will do the job?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akamai doesn't render any javascript pages into HTML by default, so if you are in need of a prerendering solution then you'll want to use https://prerender.io/

Here's an example config on how to set up the middleware with Akamai: https://community.akamai.com/thread/2288